# Why doesn't my recursive algorithm return "None"

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

I have the following for my first function (array defined under function):

```
def test(array):
    if len(array) == 1:
        return 1
    return test(array[: -1]))

array = [1, 2, 3]
test(array)
```

It returns:

```
1
```

What I thought was happening was that this 1 was being returned up through the two recursive calls until it is outputted to the GUI when it is returned to the original call.

I wrote a modified second function where I replace "return test(array[: -1])" with "return print(test(array[: -1])" to confirm by belief:

```
def test(array):
    if len(array) == 1:
        return 1
    return print(test(array[: -1]))

array = [1, 2, 3]
test(array)
```

but I get the following output:

```
1
None
```

I expected:

```
1
1
```

So shouldn't I receive a "None" or some kind of error instead of a "1" in the first function's output? What does "None" here actually mean?

Comment: Could you clarify where your confusion is? You seem to have accurately described what happens in the first case. Why do you expect it to work differently?

Comment: So it sounds like it is behaving as I thought it was based on your comment and Tiago's comment. I didn't realize "print(...)" was masking this behavior, according to Tiago. I used print() in hopes of confirming the behavior I was assuming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first function is working as it should. In the first function you are recursively removing the last element of the array until the array has only one element inside, and when that is `true` it returns 1.

When you changed `return test(array[: -1])` to `return print(test(array[: -1])` you are now doing 2 things:

1. You are printing the return value of the function `test` which as you saw in the first case, will be 1.
2. You are returning the value of the function `print` which is `None`.

So, both scenarios are working accordingly.

Comment: This makes sense.  I forgot print() and its outputs are "NoneType".

Comment: So basically, the "print()" function is not allowing me to see the behavior, rather, it masks it.

Comment: Which behavior would you like to see? If you want to see the recursive behavior, you can simply add `print(array)` as the first line of your function `test`.

Comment: I was expecting to see "1" followed by another "1" but now I understand the print function was masking this by returning "None".

Comment: Understood! Happy coding!